# How to display the facebook oauth2 login in a popup?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, facebook-social-plugins

I followed this tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) to create a facebook oauth2 login and it's working fine.
Once I click on the login button it redirects to the facebook page and after the user logs in it goes back to the application.

Now I want to modify the code so I can have a popup instead of redirecting the application to the facebook web page. I'm trying to find some material on how to do that, but couldn't find anything so far.

Does someone know what needs to be done or have some link / article on how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That has to be done in the javascript front end. From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.12

> Calling FB.login() results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup window.

Comment: Is that's the only way? Cuz I'm using springboot dependencies only. Didn't want to need adding anything else..

Comment: Well, yeah.  Unless someone has created a springboot module that injects javascript to cause the popup.